# how to place extra div within a nav container, space objects evenly and align search to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm just creating what looks like a simple navigation. Stuck in the part where I need to align things correctly.

progress: https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/bL1jxfax/

Objectives:
1) Make sure that the top reads like: Home | About Us | Links | Search
2) Make sure that the items in 1 are evenly spaced
3) Other business has that two tier nav

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav_page active">
            <a class="nav_txt" href="#">Home        
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav_txt" href="#">About us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav_txt" href="#">Links
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="search">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search 
        </button>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So do you want the search button on the same line as the menu links?

Comment: Thanks, Carl. Yes. I have made a little more progress here:https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/bL1jxfax/2/ Now the only issue is getting these other items equally spaced...

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/bL1jxfax/4/

Comment: Whoa! Thanks again. That's very close. Now just looking to keep them well spaced left to right spread across the full width of nav. Like this

[    HOME   |    About Us    |    Links   |    Search    ]

Comment: So basically you want the links and button to be evenly spaced in context of the header itself? So that they fill the header out?

Comment: @CarlEdwards yes

Answer (score 0):

If you have it inline properly, just add the margin-right of the ul li tag so it will spread to the right.

```
ul li {
  margin-right: (enter your desired amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes you need to make:

- Set the width of the navbar ul to 100%
- Display it as flexbox using display:flex and justify the space between them
- Align the contents as stretch so they can be flexible on page resize

Jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/123ujh6p/

```css
#search {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.col-sm-9 {
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav_page active">
            <a class="nav_txt" href="#">Home  
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav_txt" href="#">About Us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav_txt" href="#">Links
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="search">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search 
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```